# Minibb template not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've installed minibb forum on my server.

```
http://www.example.com/forum

$DB='mysqli';

$DBhost='localhost';
$DBname='minibb_forum';
$DBusr='not_root';
$DBpwd='not_actual_pw';

$Tf='minibbtable_forums';
$Tp='minibbtable_posts';
$Tt='minibbtable_topics';
$Tu='minibbtable_users';
$Ts='minibbtable_send_mails';
$Tb='minibbtable_banned';

$admin_usr='Admin';
$admin_pwd='specify.admin.password';
$admin_email='specify.root.admin.email.address';

$bb_admin='bb_admin.php?';

$indexphp='index.php?';

$cookiedomain='';
$cookiename='miniBBforums';
$cookiepath='';
$cookiesecure=FALSE;
$cookie_expires=108000;
$cookie_renew=1800;
$cookielang_exp=2592000;

$main_url='http://www.example.com/forum';
```

I've changed all the setting above to match mine.

I keep getting the following error:

```
TEMPLATE NOT FOUND: ./templates/user_login_form.html
```

Whenever I try opening ./templates/user_login_form.html

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /forum/templates on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

I've tried to change permissions: chmod -R o+r * when inside forum but it keeps saying the same error. I have a chmod 644 .htaccess with the following inside it:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```